# Build Succeeding but won't give correct output

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace stdd;

struct em
{
   int hours;
   double payRate;
};

int main()
{
    vector<em> emp;
    int numEmployees;
    int index;
    cout << "How Many Employees Do You Have?" << endl;
    cin >> numEmployees;
    cout << "Enter the hours worked by " << numEmployees;
    cout << "employees and their hourly rates.\n";
    for (index = 0; index < numEmployees; index++)
    {
        int tempHours;
        double tempRate;
        em emp_pay;
        cout << "Hours worked by employee #" << (index + 1);
        cout << ": ";
        cin >> tempHours;
        emp_pay.payRate = tempRate;
        cout << "Hourly pay rate for employee #";
        cout << (index + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> tempRate;
        emp_pay.payRate = tempRate;
        emp.push_back(emp_pay);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this is my code and my output looks as follows:

```
How Many Employees Do You Have?
3
Enter the hours worked by 3employees and their hourly rates.
Hours worked by employee #1: 1
Hourly pay rate for employee #1: 10
Hours worked by employee #2: 1
Hourly pay rate for employee #2: 10
Hours worked by employee #3: 1
Hourly pay rate for employee #3: 10
Program ended with exit code: 0.
```

how do i get it to display my results? First time working with structs btw

Comment: Please explain what you expect and why, including to explain in general what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: You need to iterate through the `emp` vector, printing the data. `for (auto & e : emp) std::cout << e.hours << " " << e.payRate << "\n";`

Comment: I do not see any calculation of which you could expect a result. I do not see any output code (apart from the one related to input) from which you could expect to see any output. Please explain what output you expect from which lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you never print out the contents of `emp` which, I assume is what you are trying to acheive.

To print out the contents of `emp`, you must iterate through the `vector` with the following:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < emp.size(); i++) {
  cout << "Employee #" << i << "\tHours: " << emp[i].hours
  << "\tPay rate: " << emp[i].payRate << endl;
}
```

This snippet would print out the data in the following format:

```
Employee #{{ employeeNumber }}     Hours: {{ hours }}     Pay rate: {{ payRate }}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Where do you get that naming convention from ? Look at stl/boost for example, everyting is `snake_case`. I think your statement about naming convention in C++ is nothing but outright subjective!!!

Comment: Again, better change the loop to a range-based `for`.

Comment: @aep Personally, I see a lot more classes in `PascalCase` than in `snake_case`. As for your second comment, I just wanted to keep things simple but of course, that is probably a better solution. :)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying, it is something _personal_ as you say. It's nothing conventional in C++ realm. The statement itself is completely misleading and wrong. See my examples: _STL_ & _boost_ should be 2 of the largest C++ projects that any C++ programmer would be familiar with.

Comment: @aep Fine, I must admit that both STL and boost both use `snake_case`. It might be the influence from other languages. :)

Comment: Have a read in [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) if you really need to know the C++ recommended/accepted conventions. Even there the guideline is to use `snake_case`. I don't want to _down_ _vote_ your answer since that statement is not pertaining to the question being asked. It's horribly misleading and worth being removed, though.